# Gendern in technischer Masterthesis?

Tags: gender, gender-neutrality

Aktuell schreibe ich eine Masterthesis in einer Ingenieurswissenschaft.
In meiner Arbeit gibt es Begriffe wie z.B. `Anlagenbetreiber`. Nach dem Gendern würde daraus `Anlagenbetreiber*in` werden.

Ist es zeitgemäß, solche Begriffe in einer technischen Masterthesis zu gendern?

Comment: Es gibt eine juristische Meinung dazu, die von dem, was sprachwissenschaftlich Fakt ist, konträr ist und wie man sich dazu verhält ist eine ethische/politische Frage. Man kann es aber auch als eine Frage der Mode betrachten. Oder als eine der Ästhetik. Zwar diskutiere ich das nicht ungern, aber so ist es eine Neinungsfrage und hier off topic.

Comment: Das solltest du die Personen fragen, die deine Arbeit lesen werden, also in erster Linie dein(e) Betreuer*in. Diese Person(en) wissen vielleicht auch wie deine Professor_in das sieht. Das ist insbesondere auch deshalb wichtig, weil es durchaus möglich ist dass deine BetreuerIn zwar auf gendergerechte Sprache besteht, aber eine bestimmte Form bevorzugt. Zum Beispiel könnte er/sie das Binnen-I für altmodisch, oder den Gender-Gap für übertrieben halten. Alternativ könntest du die Arbeit in Englisch verfassen; das wäre zeitgemäß _und_ du würdest das Problem umgehen.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

### Ja! Selbstverständlich muss man das gendern!

Comment: Gibt es hier keine Alternative? Z.B. wie bei *Studierende*, welches für *Studentin und Student* steht? Klingt *Arbeitgebende* unnatürlich?

Comment: @c.p.: Auch das Wort *Studierende* muss man gendern. Das ist im Akkusativ notwendig, wenn wir eine Studierende oder einen Studierenden sehen und im Dativ könnte man einer Studierenden bzw. einem Studierendem begegnen. Dasselbe trifft zu, wenn du etwas über eine Arbeitgebende oder einen Arbeitgebenden schreibst. Zur Notwendigkeit des Genderns kommen nur unnötige Kunstwörter hinzu, die die Akzeptanz dieses gesellschaftlich wichtigen Schrittes nicht wirklich verbessern.

Comment: Ok, das meint der OP mit *Gendern*. Vielleicht hätte ich in der Mehrzahl schreiben sollen, wo Gendern dann keinen Unterschied macht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Dat. m. ist aber "einem Studierenden"

Comment: Und müsste diese Antwort nicht "Ja! Selbstverständlich muss man/frau das gendern!" heißen? ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Nein.

Comment: Mir scheint, viele Deutsche verstehen nicht, dass Gendern bei euch in Österreich seit Jahren einen anderen Stellenwert hat, als heute in Deutschland.

Comment: Normalerweise ist ein Anlagenbetreiber eine Gesellschaft im rechtlichen Sinne. Wenn es sich etwa um eine GmbH handelt, kann man sagen - allerdings nur als Jurist, z.B. in einer schriftlichen Klage oder Anklage - _die XYZ-GmbH als Anlagenbetreiberin_. Ich würde das nicht Gendern nennen, sondern (grammatische) Kongruenz. Das ist ein weites Feld, wie präzise man auch bei dieser Art von Kongruenz mit dem Genus sein muss, erscheint mir nicht vollständig geklärt. Jedenfalls würden sich irgendwelche weiblichen Wesen bei einer AG als _Anlagenbetreiber_ schwerlich "nicht mitgemeint" fühlen können.

Comment: Wenn jedoch mit _Anlagenbetreiber_ eine Gruppe von natürlichen Personen gemeint ist, unter denen sich auch Frauen befinden, ist heute das Gendern angesagt. Wie notwendig das ist, um einen Text zu verstehen bzw. um sich nicht als repektloser Trampel zu outen, drüber gehen die Meinungen auseinander. Diesbezügliche Verkomplizierungen sind über ihre Künstlichkeit hinaus ästhetisch unbefriedigend. Deren Notwendigkeit wird nicht allgemein anerkannt, auch wenn derzeit im öffentlichen Sprachgebrauch fleißig gegendert wird.  Hinter der  Schwelle zum Privaten erlahmt vermutlich der genderistische Elan.

Answer (score 0):

Die Form mit Stern ist definitiv "zeitgemäß", aber *zeitgemäß* mit *gut* oder *schlecht* gleichzusetzen, wäre natürlich ein Kurzschluss.

Universitäten legen aber wohl nach dem, was man so hört, überall großen Wert darauf, das generische Maskulinum (Ärzte) durch das angeblich *gerechtere*  generische unterbrochene Femininum (Ärzt*innen, Ärzt:innen, Ärzt_innen, ÄrztInnen) zu ersetzen, da muss man sich als Studentin oder Student vermutlich sowieso anpassen.

Eventuell wäre noch *Anlagenbetreibende* eine Alternative. Das wird bei uns in der Firma zumindest gern genommen. Wenn man konsequent "die Anlagenbetreibende" schreibt, ist das zwar vielleicht nicht gerecht oder sprachlich sinnvoll, aber pragmatisch. Ich versuche im allgemeinen, männliche und weibliche Formen abwechselnd zu benutzen, aber das ist auch nur ein persönlicher Ausweg, der nicht überall akzeptiert ist.

Vielleicht gibt es dazu an Eurer Uni sogar Richtlinien. Ich würde vermutlich meine Betreuende fragen, wie das übliche Vorgehen aussieht, und mich danach richten.

Comment: Auch die/den Anlagenbetriebende(n) muss man gendern. Das löst nicht das eigentliche Problem, sondern verunstaltet die Sprache nur noch mehr.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast:  Im Singular ja, aber da wird es mit dem Stern ja auch erst so richtig hässlich. "Ein Rezept kann durch den\*die diensthabende\*n Ärzt*in auf Anforderung ausgestellt werden."

Comment: Ich habe auch nie behauptet, der Stern wäre schön. Daher habe ich ihn auch nicht verwendet. Tatsächlich ist keine der mir bekannten Lösungen schön oder gar ideal. Wahr ist aber auch, dass die Sichtbarmachung weiblicher Formen in der Sprache ein extrem wichtiges Mittel ist, um Frauen und ihre Leistungen in der Gesellschaft sichtbar zu machen. Da nehme ich gerne ein paar sprachliche Hässlichkeiten hin, die uns hoffentlich bald etwas weniger hässlich vorkommen werden, als weiterhin rund 51% aller Menschen zu diskriminieren.

Comment: Wir kommen hier in eine Meinungsdiskussion, die ich hier nicht sinnvoll finde. Die Meinung, wir würden Frauen im Jahr 2021 "diskriminieren", wenn wir das weibliche Geschlecht nicht durch gezielte Änderung der Sprache aktiv in jedem zweiten Satz sichtbar machen, teile ich nicht, aber das wird im Moment ja an jeder Ecke diskutiert, das müssen wir hier nicht tun.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Der Downvote für deine Antwort ist nicht von mir, um das klarzustellen.

Comment: @HalvarF ob es diskriminiert, sei dahingestellt, es gibt aber genügend belegte Studien, die zeigen, dass Gendern positive Effekte auf die Wahrnehmung von den verschiedenen Geschlechltern in ein und dem selben Berufsfeld hat.